# How @include works in blade templating in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I was curious about how `@include` works in Laravel Blade, I mean if we use it in a loop like this

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    @include('parts.post')
@endforeach
```

will we load this file `x` times where `x` is amount of posts or we load this file once and use it `x` times?

Thanks

Comment: What is the issue you are facing here?

Comment: well it's logical... if it's going to load the file 10 times is better to put html code in `foreach` loop instead of `@include`. I think it's going to be big difference if we load file 100 times or one and use it from memory, or am I wrong?

Comment: As a sidenote, suppressing errors (using `@` in front of functions) is generally **bad practice**, and should be avoided. You should handle and fix errors instead.

Comment: @Qirel Laravel's [Blade templates](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures) use the `@` prefix for `@foreach` and `@include`. It's not for suppressing errors.

Comment: @KirkBeard you're absolutely right! I withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blade template engine works by turning blade-html files into php-html files. `@include` will be replaced only once e.g.

```
<!-- parts/post.blade.php -->
<p>This is my post: {{$post}} </p>

<!-- some-template.blade.php -->
@foreach($posts as $post)
   @include('parts.post')
@endforeach
```

Will be rendered into the following php-html code and saved into a view file (see `storage/framework/views` if you want to see this):

```
<?php for($posts as post){ ?>
   <p>This is my post: <?php echo($post); ?> </p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: So it won't load the file `x` times. Great and thanks for your time. Now i understand how it works. I could actually check the rendered files, but didn't think about it earlier somehow, thanks again.

Comment: no, its just loaded once. In fact, the views are only rendered (i think) if you make changes to the templates. So @include is likely to be loaded less times than you hit your view!