# Creating a Blade style view templating in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Extending layouts and dividing a view file into sections, wherein "x" section goes inside "x" section of the layout when rendering. Like it's done in blade using `@extend()` and `@section()` []. I just want to implement this on my own PHP without using any library or framework. This is how blade does it :

Layout File [app.blade.php]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

View File [my-page.blade.php]

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('sidebar')
    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

Comment: <?php include('file.php')?> no ?

Comment: without the use of include or require, inside the view code.

Comment: Look at the processed .php file of that blade file and you will see how it's done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How @include works in blade templating in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977759/how-include-works-in-blade-templating-in-laravel)

Comment: No, i wanted to recreate it so I would need help with the code on how to it.